Asymptotic analysis of a linear advection-diffusion equation
Consider the linear advection-diffusion equation for $t,x>0$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} + f(x)\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = \varepsilon \frac{ \partial^2 c}{\partial x^2} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with boundary condition and initial data
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}(0,t)=0, \qquad c(x,0)=c_0(x) \tag{2}.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ is well-behaved. We wish to examine this system in the limit as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$.
Away from any boundary layers, we set $c = C+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)$ and (1) reduces to the linear transport equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + f(x)\frac{\partial C}{\partial x} = 0. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
This equation has the solution
\begin{equation}
C = \exp\Big( G\big(\zeta(x)-t\big) \Big), \qquad \text{with} \qquad \zeta(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{f(s)} \mathrm{d}s, \tag{4}
\end{equation}
such that the function $G$ can be uniquely determined from the initial conditions.
My problem arises when considering the boundary layer region. Equation (4) suggests to me that the boundary layer should be at $\zeta(x) -t$, and so I introduce the boundary layer coordinates
\begin{equation}
z = \frac{\zeta(x)-t}{\varepsilon^\alpha}, \qquad \tau = t.
\end{equation}
My first issue arises when transforming (1) using these coordinates. To calculate $\partial / \partial x$ and $\partial /\partial t$ we have via the chain rule
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \varepsilon^{-\alpha}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x} = \varepsilon^{-\alpha}\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial \tau}-\varepsilon^{-\alpha}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}.
\end{equation}
The dominant balance occurs at $\alpha=1$, and we obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\bigg(\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}\bigg)=0
\end{equation}
which is still dependent on the function $f(x)$. Could someone please tell me how to proceed? Any additional information you wish to share relating to solving (1) via asymptotics would also be appreciated.
